# Getting Array From Firestore Database

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

EDITED: The mistake was on my end. Getting the document from Firestore comes back as a list.

I upload an array to Firestore as a `List<String>` but when I try to get the array back, it comes back as a `_internalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>`.

When I try to cast it back to the list, I get this error,

```
    flutter: The following assertion was thrown building 
    StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(dirty, state:
    flutter: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot, 
    AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>>#f4f4e):
    flutter: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not 
    a subtype of type 'List<String>'
```

I then tried to do `List.from(document.data['myData'])` I get the error

```
    flutter: The following assertion was thrown building 
    StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(dirty, state:
    flutter: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot, 
    AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>>#f4f4e):
    flutter: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not 
    a subtype of type 'Iteratable<dynamic>' <--------This changed
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can get/convert the response from Firestore from a `_internalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>` to a  `List<String>`?

Comment: I never have problem like this, if I upload a List it will become List<dynamic> and never get a hashmap, please update your question with the code when upload and the data on firestore if possible

Comment: It was a mistake on my end. I had documents that had different types for the same field and one of them was a map and the others were List. Thank you